# How to retrieve the ID from the table in the database and insert it to the SMTP client?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing a web application that should send quizzes to the users automatically. Now, I am working in writing simple console application that will read the Quiz table in the database which its schema as following:
***QuizID, Title, Description, IsSent***

IsSent is a flat with Bit data type which specified the status of message sent or not. I am trying now to retrieve the QuizID and IsSent from the database and doing the following logic:
If the quiz was not sent, sends it
Else 
    don't do anything

I am writing the small amount of code and I struggled now with retrieving the QuizID and IsSent flag and apply the above logic on both of them. So HOW TO DO THAT?

My code-behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient("MAIL ADDRESS");
        MailMessage msg = null;


        try
        {

            msg = new MailMessage("yyyyyyy@gmail.com",
                "xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com", "Message from PSSP System",
                "This email sent by the system");
            msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
            sc.Send(msg);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        finally
        {
            if (msg != null)
            {
                msg.Dispose();
            }
        }


        //For requesting the Quiz_ID and check the IsSent flag for whether sending it or not
        string connString = "Data Source=localhost\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=psspdb;Integrated Security=True";
        string cmdText = "SELECT QuizID, IsSent FROM dbo.QUIZ";

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            // Open DB connection.
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn))
            {
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                While (reader != null){
                    if (reader.Read())
                        if (reader["IsSent"].Equals(0))

                }
            }
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
       long quizId;
       int isSent;       
       While (reader != null){
           if (reader.Read())
              if (reader["IsSent"].Equals(0)){
                  quizId = Convert.ToInt64(reader["quizId"]);
                  isSent = Convert.ToInt32(reader["isSent"]);
              }
       }
```

Comment: Could you please tell me what the benefit of declaring two variables and then converting them to INT? Also, what I want know, is how to read the ID and put it in the email.